# C++ Помогите преобразовать программу, что бы ввод исходных данных осуществлялся в массив записей

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, структуры

Данная программа уже имеет исходные данные, нужно преобразовать, так, что бы данные вводились пользователем в массив записей.
Пожалуйста подскажите как это лучше сделать

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct Raspisanie
{
  string day;
  string subject;
  int numberofclass;
  string surname;
};
void printinformation(Raspisanie raspisanie )
{
    cout<<"day:"<<raspisanie.day<<"\n";
    cout<<"subject:"<<raspisanie.subject<<"\n";
    cout<<"number of class:"<<raspisanie.numberofclass<<"\n";
    cout<<"surname:"<<raspisanie.surname<<"\n";
}
int main() 
{
    Raspisanie monday ={"monday" , "math", 3,"Naider"};
    Raspisanie tuesday={"tuesday", "biology", 2,"Rovinskiy"};
    Raspisanie wednesday ={"wednesday", "Literature",1,"Fyodorova"};
    Raspisanie thursday = {"thursday", "math", 4,"Naider"};
    Raspisanie friday={"friday", "English", 1,"Protas"};
    printinformation (monday);
    printinformation (tuesday);
    printinformation (wednesday);
    printinformation (thursday);
    printinformation (friday);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение с вводом и выводом информации о расписании:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

// структура расписания
struct Schedule final 
{
  std::string day;
  std::string subject;
  int number_class;
  std::string surname;
};

// функция для ввода информации
Schedule enterData()
{
   Schedule schedule;
   
   std::cout << "Введите день недели:";
   std::cin >> schedule.day;
   std::cout << std::endl;
   
   std::cout << "Введите предмет изучения:";
   std::cin >> schedule.subject;
   std::cout << std::endl;
   
   std::cout << "Введите номер класса(число):";
   std::cin >> schedule.number_class;
   std::cout << std::endl;
   
   std::cout << "Введите фамилию:";
   std::cin >> schedule.surname;
   std::cout << std::endl;
   
   return schedule;
}

// функция для вывода информации
void printinformation(const Schedule& raspisanie )
{
    std::cout << "day: " << raspisanie.day << std::endl;
    std::cout << "subject: " << raspisanie.subject << std::endl;
    std::cout << "number of class: " << raspisanie.number_class << std::endl;
    std::cout << "surname: " << raspisanie.surname << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    // количество уроков
    constexpr int count_lesson = 1;
    // контейнер для расписаний
    std::vector<Schedule> schedules(count_lesson);
    // вводим информацию о расписании
    for (int i = 0; i < schedules.size(); ++i)
    {
        schedules[i] = enterData();
    }
    // выводим информацию о расписании
    for (int i = 0; i < schedules.size(); ++i)
    {
        printinformation(schedules[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не хватает `#include <string>`, `std::` и какого-нибудь хедера для `size_t`.

Comment: @tocic все работает без #include<string>, обычно по умолчанию в iostream строка есть, size_t аналогично. std:: вкусовщина в данном примере :)

Comment: Работает на одной реализации, но может не работать на другой. Лучше не писать непортабельный код без необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, поправил